# Looking for MySQL performance advice for database-heavy app

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I'm creating a messaging app using jQuery, PHP and MySQL. Every time a user enters a message, I store it in a MySQL table. On the receiving users end, I basically just added a Javascript timer to check the database every X number of seconds for new messages.

The system works well but is this going to be a performance problem? For example, let's say I have 1000 users and I'm hitting a MySQL table every 5 seconds for each user.

Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this table? What type of queries are you executing? Have you run an EXPLAIN for those queries?

Comment: When a user enters a message, it has a conversation_id. So I then am constantly checking for any new entries with the respective conversation_id. No to the question about EXPLAIN and indexes...

Comment: Well unless you properly index your table, then performance will get slower and slower for selects as the volume of data in the table grows

Comment: Okay, but let's say I have indexes, I should be good?

Comment: No guarantees (depends on your vague definition of good), but without indexes I will guarantee that you'll be bad

Answer (score 0):

With your actual architecture, your SGBD will get a heart attack :)

The solution reside on implementation of Web Socket
in back-end only 1 instance of PHP check if there is a new update on database, if there is, PHP can invoke a web service to your Web-Socket Server (like NodeJS), and Server send the message to the client